# CakePHP: Weird Contain Behavior

Tags: cakephp

I'm having some really weird 'Contain' behavior. Whenever I leave $restaurants commented, $spas returns the contained data (assigned in the beforeFilter(), but when I uncomment $restaurants, it ignores the contain statement. (I've even tried cloning the $spas function and naming it "$restaurants" and the same thing happens..

```
class CouponsController extends AppController {

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Coupon->contain(array('Vendor' => array('VendorLocation'), 'Category'));
    }


    public function index() {
        $showPerPage = 4;


        //$restaurants = $this->Coupon->findAllBycategory_id('1', '', '', $showPerPage);   

        $spas = $this->Coupon->find('all', array('limit' => $showPerPage, 'conditions' => array('Coupon.category_id' => 3)));
        $this->set('spas', $spas);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the commented line to a regular find query like `$restaurants = $this->Coupon->find('all', array('conditions' => 'category_id' => 1, 'limit' => $showPerPage))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you attach this behavior in `$actsAs` variable on Coupon model?

Or you can attach on Controller:

```
$this->Coupon->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
$this->Coupon->contain(array('Vendor' => array('VendorLocation'), 'Category'));
```

And detach wherever you want:

```
$this->Coupon->Behaviors->detach('Containable');
```